# Calculating a number or finding averages with one number repeating multiple times

Tags: statistics, average

I'm having difficulty finding averages when some numbers in my data repeats over 9000 times. (Sorry, as I'm using google sheets and I'm unwilling to write the value 9989, 9049 times)

When finding an average, or average for standard deviations, or a dataset for IQR is it possible to write a value Nth number of times?

For instance:

`11, 11, 11, 14, 15, 16 (repeated 65 times), 17, 18`
or
`9989^9049` (which isn't correct at all) just an example of how trying to display a single value.

Is there a simply way to calculate an average when you have several multiples of the same value?

Comment: What's wrong with just computing the average, regardless of duplicates? If a number is repeated x times, add it to the average x times.

Comment: I'm confused, if I have 500 numbers and 200 of them have duplicates over 50; how would I add it to the average that many times without writing thousands of numbers over.

Comment: Multiplication... repetitions $\times$ number.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I would need to display the large number of data. Not just the average result. I only wanted to represent the data for statistical purposes